# What is unsafe in this extreme simple thread Monitor implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, monitor

I am new in thread syncronization. I was reading many implementations of conditional variables, like boost::threads and pthread for win32. I just implemented this quite simple monitor with wait/notify/noifyall, and i guess that there are many hidden problems with it, that I would like to discover from more experienced people. Any suggestion?

```
class ConditionVar
{

public :
    ConditionVar () : semaphore ( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) , total_waiters (0)
    {
        semaphore = ::CreateSemaphoreA ( NULL , 0 /* initial count */ , LONG_MAX /* max count */ , NULL );
    }

    ~ConditionVar ()
    {
        ::CloseHandle ( semaphore ) ;       
    }


public :
    template <class P>
    void Wait ( P pred )
    {
        while ( !pred() ) Wait();
    }

public :

    void Wait ( void )
    {
        INTERLOCKED_WRITE_RELEASE(&total_waiters,total_waiters + 1 );
        ::WaitForSingleObject ( semaphore , INFINITE );
    }

    //! it will notify one waiter
    void Notify ( void )
    {
        if ( INTERLOCKED_READ_ACQUIRE(&total_waiters) )
        {
            Wake (1);
        }
    }

    void NotifyAll (void )
    {
        if ( INTERLOCKED_READ_ACQUIRE(&total_waiters) )
        {
            std::cout << "notifying " << total_waiters ;
            Wake ( total_waiters );
        }
    }

protected :
    void Wake ( int count )
    {
        INTERLOCKED_WRITE_RELEASE(&total_waiters,total_waiters - count );
        ::ReleaseSemaphore ( semaphore , count , NULL );
    }

private :
    HANDLE semaphore;
    long    total_waiters;
};
```

Comment: this makes use of the boost library?

Comment: well, i just copied the INTERLOCKED_READ_ACQUIRE / INTERLOCKED_WRITE_RELEASE macros, to read/write the counters to memory using memory fences.

Comment: @Isalamon: I think he wants to roll his own condvar class using Boost.Threads for inspiration.

Comment: Unless you are doing this for fun/learning purposes, I think you should use Boost.Threads. It has been used and reviewed by many people more experienced than you and I. ;-) Multi-threading is really hard to do correctly, so it's wise to use already debugged/tested libraries.

Comment: i am doing it for fun/learning :) specially to learn about which tests should i make.

Answer (score 2):

I think bad things will happen if you copy your instance since both copies will use the same sempahore. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but it might confuse people if the semantics aren't entirely clear.

You can easily fix this with a similar approach to what [boost::noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) uses (or use boost).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Boost's implementation of `wait()`, because it takes an RAII lock object to make sure access to the shared condition state is synchronized. RAII makes it easier to write exception-safe code.

I have annotated the sample code found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref):

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mut;
bool data_ready;

void process_data();

void wait_for_data_to_process()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);  // Mutex acquired here (RAII).
    while(!data_ready) // Access to data_ready is sync'ed via mutex 'mut'
    {
        // While we are blocking, the mutex is released so
        // that another thread may acquire it to modify data_ready.
        cond.wait(lock);

        // Mutex is acquired again upon exiting cond.wait(lock)
    }
    process_data();

    // Mutex is released when lock goes out of scope.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using WinAPI functions, its probably better to use `InterlockedIncrement(...)` and `InterlockedDecrement(...)` instead of `INTERLOCKED_WRITE_RELEASE(&total_waiters,total_waiters + 1 );` and `INTERLOCKED_WRITE_RELEASE(&total_waiters,total_waiters - count );` respectively.

Comment: it is only a macro... it means an atomic operation to increase/decrease the variable

Comment: But it is needlessly convoluted. If you're tied to the Win32 API anyway, why not use the atomic operations provided there? Other Win32 programmers will be familiar with those already.

Answer (score 0):

(self answer)

i found a big mistake.

CondVars have an external lock... and this hasnt.